# The time is different before and after parsing with time.Parse

Tags: go

I need to receive a time as a string, parse it and then present it as a string again:

```golang
package main

import ("fmt"; "time")

func main() {
  const timeLayout = "Mon, Jan 2, 2006 15:04 PM"
  sourceTime :=      "Mon, Apr 7, 2025 7:36 PM"
  myTime, err := time.Parse(timeLayout, sourceTime)
  if err != nil { panic(err) }
  fmt.Printf("\t\tsourceTime = \"%s\"\n myTime.Format(timeLayout) = \"%s\"\n",
    sourceTime, myTime.Format(timeLayout))
}
```

It was my expected output:

```
                sourceTime = "Mon, Apr 7, 2025 7:36 PM"
 myTime.Format(timeLayout) = "Mon, Apr 7, 2025 7:36 PM"
```

But I received this strange output:

```
                sourceTime = "Mon, Apr 7, 2025 7:36 PM"
 myTime.Format(timeLayout) = "Mon, Apr 7, 2025 19:36 PM"
```

I did not change something in my variable, so why I received a different result with same layout? I should not change this time layout. But I need to receive the source string as a result again.

Comment: In the format, use 3 for hours instead of 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time layout is using a 24 hour clock (e.g. 15:04 instead of 3:04), so when you format it you get 19 instead of 7.  If you want a 12 hour clock then your time layout should be `"Mon, Jan 2, 2006 3:04 PM"`